# How to use dropzone.js with PERL(cgi)

Tags: javascript, perl, cgi, dropzone.js

I'm to learn how to use dropzone.js and perl(cgi).
Dropzone.js has good tutorials on how to upload files using PHP, is there an easy way to use dropzone with perl(cgi).

I found a tutorial that works very well with PHP.

```
<?php

//upload.php

$folder_name = 'upload/';

if(!empty($_FILES))
{
 $temp_file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
 $location = $folder_name . $_FILES['file']['name'];
 move_uploaded_file($temp_file, $location);
}
?>
```

HTML

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>How to Upload a File using Dropzone.js with PHP</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>        
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.5.1/dropzone.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.5.1/dropzone.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <br />
   <h3 align="center">How to Upload a File using Dropzone.js with PHP</h3>
   <br />
   
   <form action="upload.php" class="dropzone" id="dropzoneFrom">

   </form>
   
    
   </form>
   <br />
   <br />
   <div align="center">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="submit-all">Upload</button>
   </div>
   <br />
   <br />
   <div id="preview"></div>
   <br />
   <br />
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
 
 Dropzone.options.dropzoneFrom = {
  autoProcessQueue: true,
  acceptedFiles:".png,.jpg,.gif,.bmp,.jpeg",
 
 };

 
 
 
});
</script>
```

Is there an easy way to convert the PHP code to CGI.

PERL (My perl code doesn't work)

```
my $query   = new CGI;

my $id        = $query->param("id");
my $filename  = $query->param("name");
my $myName    = $query->param("name");
 
 
my ($name, $path, $ext) = fileparse($filename, qr/\.[^.]*/ );

# my ($name, $path, $ext) = fileparse($filename, qr/\.[^.]*/ );


my $filehandle = $query->upload("name");

my $FILEWITHPATH = 'C:/xxx/xx/xxx/xxx/xxx/' . $myName;

open ( UPLOADFILE,">$FILEWITHPATH") or die "Error: $!\n";
binmode UPLOADFILE;
while ( <$filehandle> )
{
    print UPLOADFILE;
}
close UPLOADFILE;

1;
```

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Show us your Perl code.

Comment: @DaveCross Hey Dave, forgot to add my perl code. I have updated the question with the perl code that I'm using, but is not working ;/

Comment: "Is not working" is not a very good problem description. What unexpected behaviour are you seeing? Is something written to the web server error log?

Comment: You need to look at what's in the form that your javascript submits. Find out the name of the upload element, and then do what https://metacpan.org/dist/CGI/view/lib/CGI.pod#Processing-a-file-upload-field says. This is like a normal file upload where you've written the `<input type="file">` element yourself, just with a generated one. All you need to know is its name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [the `upload` method in CGI](https://metacpan.org/dist/CGI/view/lib/CGI.pod#Processing-a-file-upload-field). From the documentation of [dropzone.js](https://docs.dropzone.dev/) I took that this works asynchronously. Every time you drop a file, the upload just works.

Here's my example HTML file. I deleted most of this from your example. There is no submit button, as it just submits every time you drop one.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.5.1/dropzone.css" />
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.5.1/dropzone.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form
            action="upload.pl"
            class="dropzone"
            id="my-awesome-dropzone">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then have a Perl script like this. Mine is called `upload.pl`. It needs to be executable, so if you are on Linux, make sure you set `chmod u+x` on it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;

my $q = CGI->new;

# this is the HTTP response header
print $q->header;

if ( my $io_handle = $q->upload('file') ) {
    my $filename = $q->param('file'); # this should really be sanitized

    my $buffer;
    open ( my $out_file,'>', "upload/$filename" );
    while ( my $bytesread = $io_handle->read($buffer,1024) ) {
        print $out_file $buffer;
    }
}
```

It will take the name of the file, and write the content to a file with the same name in a folder called `upload/` next to where the script is.

You should probably **not use the real file names** as that opens you up to various security problems. You can read more about this [at OWASP](https://owasp.org/www-community/vulnerabilities/Unrestricted_File_Upload). Instead you should generate your own file names. If you require the original name, store this alongside the new file name in your database, or wherever you put information about the files to process them further.

Please also note that CGI is an outdated technology, and you should probably use something more modern than that.